# Android Studio draw animation

Tags: android-studio, animation, draw

I am making Space Invaders for school project. Right now I want to animate background (so user have feeling that ship is moving forward in space).

I saw here some ideas with activity, but I am using layout from java class and not from layout.

```
` display.getSize(size);
    spaceInvadersEngine = new SpaceInvadersEngine(this, size.x, size.y);
    setContentView(spaceInvadersEngine);`
```

In `SpaceInvadersEngine` I have

```
  private void draw(){
   
    if (ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
        canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundImage,0,0,null);
```

Is there a way to animate this `backgroundImage` by Y-coordinate using draw() or to draw 2 different bitmaps that will slide and make this moving effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is stuck on parallax effect for an Android Studio I found all explained  [here](http://gamecodeschool.com/android/coding-a-parallax-scrolling-background-for-android/)